# My USB files look like they are encrypted they can't be read or opened

Tags: windows, usb, encryption, data-recovery

Hello people i have one problem that deleted a lot of my files i ran my USB as always but this time I noticed a problem main folder was normal  also one of them inside which the other files are in  looks like normal instead of files inside is like this on picture i don't know what happened.

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTLxy.jpg)

after I try to open some of the files or folders I get the following.

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05xDI.jpg)

My files have jumped from 2 GB to 80 GB my usb doesn't even have that much memory
So after that I deleted that folder by accident   i took out and put the usb back and on the windows it pop up the message.

"there is a problem with this drive. scan the drive and fix it"

And i did it after that i got a message that the problem was solved but my folder just disappeared from usb  all other folders and files are fine.

And  now I don't know what to do can I restore a folder that looks like it was damaged plus deleted or whatever it is... what are the chances?
This folder is very important to me and thanks to everyone who can help :)

Comment: I have bad news for you.  The files are either encrypted and you deleted the files when you delete the folder or the files are simply corrupted.  I am putting money on them being corrupted.  Either way, you permanently deleted the folder that contained the files.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate, this USB drive seems very much so corrupted. Even if it wasn't, you still, unfortunately, deleted the files and folder.

You may be able to salvage them with [this guide from Microsoft on restoring deleted files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/recover-lost-files-on-windows-10-61f5b28a-f5b8-3cc2-0f8e-a63cb4e1d4c4), but with how the drive looks, it may be a lost cause.